# Change recorded macro to process all data [Need Help on Loop and Syntax]

Tags: excel, vba

I have recorded this macro in excel. The idea is to go through all rows (100)
and repeat the SUB. I think i figured the proper algorithm (I have basic Turbo Pascal knowlege).

Here is my algorithm:

**Create a loop that is using a variable, i, for counting.**
**For i from 2** (we start from row 2, row 1 has headers) **to 200** (even if we initially have 100 rows by the time the scrip will finish executing we will have doubled the amount of rows)

**Do the sub**

How do I make **Rows("2:2")** for example to reference the current value of i.

How do **Rows("3:3")** to use the value i+1.

How do I make **Range("B2")** to use the value B(i)

I am stuck with the loop and the proper syntax Please help. Also since I want to get deeper into the topic could you please suggest some good sources? I was not really interested in coding after during high school, but now I want to get deeper into the topic.

```
Sub Macro2()
    Rows("2:2").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Rows("3:3").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("B2").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Cut
    Range("A3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim i As Long
For i = 100 To 2 Step -1
    Rows(i).Copy
    Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
    Cells(i, 2).Cut Cells(i + 1, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

I removed the `.Select` and `.Activate` It slows down the code. See [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for good guidance on such.

When adding or subtracting rows it is best to iterate from bottom to top.  The `Step - 1` does that.  It starts at row 100 and goes up till row 2.

Another note you will want to designate the sheet so that it looks at the correct sheet:

```
Sub Macro2()
Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim i As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet.
For i = 100 To 2 Step -1
    ws.Rows(i).Copy
    ws.Rows(i + 1).Insert shift:=xlDown
    ws.Cells(i, 2).Cut ws.Cells(i + 1, 1)
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That worked like warm knife through butter. Thank you. Did I understand corectly that we are processing the rows from the bottom up?  Any advice on where to learn more?

Comment: @VictorWarhol Glad it worked.  Please mark as correct by clicking the grey/green check by the answer.  To learn, there are many free websites that will walk through step by step.  Start [HERE](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/macros/what_is_vba2013.php).

Comment: Great! Thank you again.